# PHP sessions don't seem to work after login! Wamp - 4 sessions created / login?

Tags: php, mysql, windows, session, wamp

this is my first question asked on SO so please excuse me if I go against some of the post etiquette - I'll do my best to explain my problem clearly, and I have searched for previous questions but none match my issue as far as I'm aware.

Background: Running on WAMP server 2.4 with Apache 2.4.4 and PHP 5.4.12 - Please let me know if you need any specifics.

I've been working on a new webapp project and seem to have run into a problem while trying to get PHP sessions working. My login process works as follows;

- Once a user submits details and they are crosschecked with those stored in a Mysql database, a session is created and they are redirected to a temporary protected page.
- The temporary page checks that the user has a valid session and if so displays a welcome message.
- If the user does not have a valid session then they receive an error.

PROBLEM: Whenever I login (successfully might I add) I'm redirected and receive the error message "You are not authorized to access this page."

Here is the code for the login process (process_login.php):

```
<?php
include_once 'db_connect.php';
include_once 'functions.php';

sec_session_start(); // Our custom secure way of starting a PHP session.

if (isset($_POST['email'], $_POST['p'])) {
$email = $_POST['email'];
$password = $_POST['p']; // The hashed password.


//Form data error handling.
if ($email == "" || $password == ""){
    echo "login failed";
    exit();

} else {
 //DB stuff.
 $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT id, username, password, salt 
 FROM members
   WHERE email = ?
    LIMIT 1");  
$stmt->bind_param('s', $email);  // Bind "$email" to parameter.
$stmt->execute();    // Execute the prepared query.
$stmt->store_result();

// get variables from result.
$stmt->bind_result($user_id, $username, $db_password, $salt);
$stmt->fetch();
// hash the password with the unique salt.
$password = hash('sha512', $password . $salt);
    if ($stmt->num_rows == 1) {
        // If the user exists we check if the account is locked
        // from too many login attempts 

        if (checkbrute($user_id, $mysqli) == true) {
            // Account is locked 
            // Send an email to user saying their account is locked
            return false;
        } else {
            // Check if the password in the database matches
            // the password the user submitted.
            if ($db_password == $password) {
                // Password is correct!
                // Get the user-agent string of the user.
                $user_browser = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
                // XSS protection as we might print this value
                $user_id = preg_replace("/[^0-9]+/", "", $user_id);
                $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user_id;
                // XSS protection as we might print this value
                $username = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+/", "", $username);

                $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
                $_SESSION['login_string'] = hash('sha512', $password . $user_browser);      

                header('Location: ../protected_page.php');
            } else {
                // Login failed 
                // Password is not correct
                // We record this attempt in the database
                $now = time();
                $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO login_attempts(user_id, time)
                                VALUES ('$user_id', '$now')");

                header('Location: ../index.php?error=1');
            }
        } 
}
```

Here is the code for my session_start function (sec_session_start() )

```
function sec_session_start() {
$session_name = 'sec_session_id';   // Set a custom session name
$secure = true;
// This stops JavaScript being able to access the session id.
$httponly = true;
// Forces sessions to only use cookies.
if (ini_set('session.use_only_cookies', 1) === FALSE) {
    header("Location: ../error.php?err=Could not initiate a safe session (ini_set)");
    exit();
}
// Gets current cookies params.
$cookieParams = session_get_cookie_params();
session_set_cookie_params($cookieParams["lifetime"],
    $cookieParams["path"], 
    $cookieParams["domain"], 
    $secure,
    $httponly);
// Sets the session name to the one set above.
session_name($session_name);
session_start();            // Start the PHP session 
session_regenerate_id();    // regenerated the session, delete the old one.
```

Here is my temporary test code (protected_page.php); 
-note I'm new to this and seem to be having trouble posting my html.

```
<?php
include_once 'includes/db_connect.php';
include_once 'includes/functions.php';
sec_session_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Secure Login: Protected Page</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php if (login_check($mysqli) == true) {?>
            <p>Welcome <?php echo htmlentities($_SESSION['username']); ?>!</p>
            <p>
                This is an example protected page.  To access this page, users
                must be logged in.  At some stage, we'll also check the role of
                the user, so pages will be able to determine the type of user
                authorised to access the page.
            </p>
            <p>Return to <a href="index.php">login page</a></p>
        <?php } else {?>
            <p>
                <span class="error">You are not authorized to access this page.</span> Please <a href="index.php">login</a>.
            </p>
        <?php }?>
    </body>
</html>
```

As far as any other specifics that might make a difference - the login form is loaded through a sidebar and sends

Any help is much appreciated! I'm semi new to this stuff and I've spent 5+ hours fiddling and can't seem to figure it out. Login works, the session code (as far as I'm aware) makes sense and SHOULD be working - ugh halp me.

ADDED NOTE: I've checked my C:/wamp/etc/ file and cleared the sessions, just by logging in apparently 4 session files are created? I think this must have something to do with it.

http://puu.sh/71Lhm.png

Comment: Can you output the array that's generated by `session_get_cookie_params`?

Comment: @dethtron5000 Hi there, I take it I just do this by adding: `<?php $array = session_get_cookie_params(); while (list($key,$val) = each($array)) { echo "$key => $val"; } ?> `If so this is what's output; lifetime => 0path => /domain => secure => 1httponly => 1 puu.sh/71Mqo.png Thanks for the help btw.

Comment: `print_r(session_get_cookie_params());` works too ;).

Answer (score 0):

Okay I ended up solving my own problem, but I'm going to leave the answer here incase anybody has a similar issue with WAMP. (I think it's because I was using WAMP)

In my custom session function (sec_session_start) I had the option for $secure  enabled. Though I believe this is only functional when you have it live on a production server using HTTPS. (Not on my local machine.) My reasoning could be wrong, but I changed the value of

```
$secure = true;

to

$secure = false;
```

And it worked! Great success.